# How Console reference variable refers to some other class method

Tags: java, object, console

I was strucked in a place that i cannot create new instance for Console class. So i took the source code of jdk and then look into it. Then i got cleared that it was declared as "public final class Console........"... So i understood that the final class cannot be instantiated. But that is not my actual doubt. Here in the SCJP Book, i came across a line of code that tells me as `Console c = System.console()`

Here we cannot create new instance for console class, so creating a reference variable c. Then What is that System.console actually is?? In the book it is told as

```
    Keep in mind that it's possible for your Java program to be running in an environment that doesn't have access to a console object, so be sure that your invocation of System.console() actually returns a valid console reference and not null.
```

So then i entered to look up source code for System.console().

There i happen to see System as final class and console() as static method inside that.

So how can a Console reference object refer to that console method in system class.. 
What is the link between these two. I thought of a polymorphic reference. 
But that is not because it doesn't pass IS-A Test. So please explain me in detail about this.

Hope my question is clear.  Thanks in advance. !

Comment: It's not: we cannot create a new instance for console class, so create a reference variable. The reference variable IS a new instance. It's just created by calling a static method on System. PS: Beginner is written with 2 n's :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*the final class cannot be instantiated*

That is wrong , `final` class cannot be subclassed. It can be instantiated using the `new` operator if its constructor is visible . I guess `Console` class has `private` constructor. **Abstract** classes cannot be instantited. See the [JLS 8.1.1.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1.2):

> A class can be declared final if its definition is complete and no subclasses are desired or required.
>
> **It is a compile-time error if the name of a final class appears in the extends clause (§8.1.4) of another class declaration; this implies that a final class cannot have any subclasses.**

[System.console()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#console())

> Returns the unique Console object associated with the current Java virtual machine, if any.
>
> Whether a virtual machine has a console is dependent upon the underlying platform and also upon the manner in which the virtual machine is invoked. If the virtual machine is started from an interactive command line without redirecting the standard input and output streams then its console will exist and will typically be connected to the keyboard and display from which the virtual machine was launched. If the virtual machine is started automatically, for example by a background job scheduler, then it will typically not have a console.
>
> **If this virtual machine has a console then it is represented by a unique instance of this class which can be obtained by invoking the System.console() method**.
>
> **If no console device is available then an invocation of that method will return null.**

`console()` is some sort of a factory method which gives you back an object of `Console` associated with the current JVM . The `System` class has knowledge of the JVM in which it is running and it is the perfect candidate to give you back the `Console` object.

```
Console c = System.console();
```

`System.console()` gives us back a reference to the `Console` object and you are assigning the object reference to variable `c`. This way you can use that reference variable `c` to access the properties or methods of `Console` object.

Comment: Or `null` if there's no console to return. For example, run your application that executes `Console console = System.console();` in your Eclipse or Netbeans IDE and then run the same application from your OS terminal.

Comment: Thankyou @The New Idiot..  Now i am clear and able to get things clearly.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the mistake in your understanding is here:

> So i understood that the final class cannot be instantiated

**Final classes cannot be extended but can be instantiated.** FYI it is the abstract class than cannot be instantiated.